# Convert string to table ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, html-table

I'm using ASP.Net MVC. How can I convert a `;` and `=` delimited string like `Color=Red;Size=28;Price=45$;` to html table like:

[image]

I want that user can add rows to table and edit this like:

[image]

and string change to `Color=Red;Size=28;Price=45$;Tel=12345678` when user wants to save the data. I tried some jQuery plugins like `jtable`but I was unsuccessful. Any Idea or solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string to a table like this:

```
// Remove the final ; if one exists:
if (tableString.substring(tableString.length - 1) == ';') {
    tableString = tableString.substring(0, tableString.length - 1);
}

var tableHtml = 
    "<table><tr><td>" + 
    tableString // where table string is something like 'Color=Red;Size=28;Price=45$'
        .replace(";", "</tr><tr>")
        .replace("=", "</td><td>") + 
    "</td></tr>";
```

...and your table to a string like this (using JQuery):

```
var tableString = 
    $("table tr").each(function() {
        return $(this).children("td").text().join("=");
    })
    .join(";");
```